# jqplot : Plot going out of the axes range

Tags: jqplot

I'm unable to figure out what could be a reason for this. I have tried autoscaling, canvasaxistickrenderer, linearaxistickrenderer etc but nothing seems to work.

[image]

These are my y axis options :

```
var y1AxisOptions = {
        show : true,
        pad : 0,
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        rendererOptions: { alignTicks: true },
        tickOptions: {
                mark: 'cross',
                showMark: true,
                showGridline: true,                          
                markSize: 5,                                 
                show: true,                                  
                showLabel: true,                             
                formatString:"%'d " ,                        
                fontSize: '8pt'                              
        },
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        autoscale: true,
        useSeriesColor : true,
        syncTicks : true,
        labelOptions: {           
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana',    
                    fontWeight: 'bold',   
                    fontSize: '10pt'       
         }  
    }
```

Please provide any insight as to what could be causing this. Much thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code behind this graph please?

Comment: Actually I figured out the problem. When I round off every value before plotting using parseInt then the graph plots correctly. The whole code is quite big and customized according to my application. Ive added the options for yaxis.